# how to create Views exposed filter with fields from custom table

Tags: views

I have one of custom table with fields named `title` and `id`. Now I want to add the title field in views exposed filter as drop down.

How to create exposed filter for this?

Could anyone explain where I can find this?

Answer (score 1):

It should depend on how you are exposing the field to views, make sure views know about field  and filter handler, so as an example in your hook_views_data() your title field should be exposed in following way -

```
// name field
$data['exposed']['title'] = array(
    'title' => t('Title'),
    'help' => t('title for record'),
    'field' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_field',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_string',
    ),
 'sort' => array(
        'handler' => 'views_handler_sort',
    ),
);
```